# Fast resize jpg file without lose exif c# Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have been searching for long to find good way to resize my jpg files without losing exif properties but:

- writablebitmap destroy my exif and is slow
- available libraries are not supported or too slow

I don't need quality, image can be 1px x 1 px small but I need to save jpg file strucure with exif data. Anyone of you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might try the [Nokia Imaging SDK](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/nokia-imaging-sdk.html) - based on [this post](http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/242007-EXIF-data) it sounds like it does preserve EXIF data at least some of the time.

Comment: yes, I tried Nokia's SDK and there is another issue. I use Virtualized Data, where I generate current list-box items in "real-time", unfortunelly overrided `this[int index]` in my Virtualized Data class doesn't support async functions, Nokia SDK use async method to final resize operation.